# \maketitle error in apa6e document class Underfull \hbox

Tags: titles, apa6

I am writing a research paper in Apa6 format using the apa6e document class.
Everything works but not the \maketitle command.
I got the error

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4--4
 []\T1/lmr/m/n/12 Mar-cel Karas
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4--4
 []\T1/lmr/m/n/12 Au-thor Note
! Undefined control sequence.
\HyOrg@maketitle ...par \RaggedRight \@authornote
                                                  \mspart {
```

Meanwhile, I defind the header as

```
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{lit.bib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\title{What plans and ideas are existing in the world community to prevent an economic disaster 
when the oil resources will dry up in eight years? Which organizations might have worked out 
the best masterplan, and is this even enough?}
\shorttitle{Oil free econonmies}
\author{Marcel Karas}
\date{23/4/2020}
```

and the the main.tex as

```
\input{header.tex}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
Test text
\cite{article1ReferenceName}
\input{content/introduction.tex}
\input{content/body.tex}
\input{content/conclusion.tex}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

For me it looks like an error in the way I defined the attributes author and title but I have no idea how to fix it. Thanks for your help.